# Call a function from complex UITabbarcontroller that all view controllers use

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a problem that is taking me time to solve... It is about the way my UITabBarController class interacts with the rest of the view controllers it owns.

This is what I have thought for my application. I don't know if it is the most convenient, that's why I ask for help.

First. In my Scene delegate i have:

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = TabBar()
```

*TabBar is my Custom Class of UITabBarController.

My goal is to have a User type that updates in all view controllers when a function that requires it is called.

I've tried addchild and protocols from TabBar() but I haven't been able to set it correctly.

basic scheme

1. Scene Delegate
2. TabBar

- Receives user information from the database and saves it in a User type variable.
- I define the viewcontrollers[HomeController, ProfileCont....] and pass User type

3. When I am in the Profile controller (for example), and the user clicks on a button, I want the User variable of my TabBar to be updated, and also to be updated in the Home Controller, ProfileController.... (all of them)

Sorry for so much text, but I wanted to explain it in the best possible way.

I attach some code.

Thanks for the help!

```
    class TabBar: UITabBarController {
        
        private var user: User?
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            view.backgroundColor = .white
            UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
            UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .lightGray
            tabBar.tintColor = .black
    
            fetchUserData()
            
        }
        
        func fetchUserData() {
            print("hey")
            guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            Service.shared.fetchUserData(uid: currentUid) { user in
                self.user = user
                self.setupVCs()
            }
        }
    
        func setupVCs() {
            
            guard let user = self.user else { return }
            
            viewControllers = [
                
                createNavController(for: HomeController(user: user), title: NSLocalizedString("Pedidos", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "pedidos")!),
                createNavController(for: SignUpController(), title: NSLocalizedString("Mapa", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "location")!),
                createNavController(for: InformePeriodos(user: user), title: NSLocalizedString("Ganancias", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "euro")!),
                createNavController(for: RetirarEfectivo(user: user), title: NSLocalizedString("Agenda", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "calendar")!),
                createNavController(for: PerfilController(user: user), title: NSLocalizedString("Perfil", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "person")!)
                
            ]
            
        }
      
       
        fileprivate func createNavController(for rootViewController: UIViewController,title: String,image: UIImage) -> UIViewController {
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
            navController.tabBarItem.title = title
            navController.tabBarItem.image = image
            return navController
            
        }
    
       
    }
```

Here my Profile controller button action

```
    @objc func confirmar(){
                
           //efectivo, and gP and retiro are some data
           DriverService.shared.updateRetiro(efectivo: saldoEfectivo, gP: gananciasPagadas, retiro: doubleinputValue) {
                
                guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
                Service.shared.fetchUserData(uid: currentUid) { user in
                    self.user = user
                    self.configureUI()
                    //i need to call FETCHUSERDATA FROM MY TABBAR HERE?
                    self.removeSpinner()
                }
                
           }
                          
     }
```

i think that call fetchuserdata in my profileController can resolve part of the problem

Comment: Is User a Core Data entity? What does Service do?

Comment: There's many ways to solve this, you could say, in general, that you need the user to be the same for all view controllers. Then you might want to have only one places that updates this user and all other parts of your app access this user from this particular class so you don't have different instances around.

Comment: But if what you want is a solution for this exact scenario you are coding, then you could. 
1. Post a `Notification` using `NotificationCenter` every time you update the user and you can be listening to that notification on your VCs, the notification can have the User so you can access it.
2. You could fetchUserData and update the user on your VCs on `viewWillAppear` although this would mean that you have to constantly call the API

Comment: Shared user for the variable . Create a subclass of UIViewCintroller type you use for all view controller initialised from tab bar. This UIViewCintroller should register to user type changed notifications. The user type should also have a function to update it an notify changes.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! The User type is nothing more than a Struct with string and Int...
My first idea was to use the user variable from the TabBar for all the viewcontrollers, and call from any viewcontroller to update the user variable of the TabBar . I perfectly understand how to proceed, but I don't know how to implement it at the code level. I am new to iOS.
I appreciate any help
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I think Notification center could be a good solution. But I don't know if it is the best practice. could it slow down the memory or something like that? continually looking at notifications?

Comment: Notifications consume time only when the user date will send the notification. When this happens the notifications center will cal the methods assigned by each of the viewController. It is like if user data was calling each view controller . The difference is that user does not (and does not need to) know anything about those VC.

Comment: thanks so much everyone. question solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the solution if helps everyone with same issue

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import CoreLocation

    class TabBar: UITabBarController {
        
        private var user: User?
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
           
            fetchUserData()
            
            let nc = NotificationCenter.default
            nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateUser), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateUser"), object: nil)

        }
        
        
        @objc func updateUser() {
            
            print("updateUser")
            guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            Service.shared.fetchUserData(uid: currentUid) { user in
                self.user = user
                self.setupVCs()
            }
            
        }
       
        
        // MARK: - Helper Functions
      
        func fetchUserData() {
            print("hey")
            guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            Service.shared.fetchUserData(uid: currentUid) { user in
                self.user = user
                self.setupVCs()
            }
        }

        func setupVCs() {
            
            guard let user = self.user else { return }
            
            viewControllers = [
                
                createNavController(for: HomeController(user: user), title: NSLocalizedString("Pedidos", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "pedidos")!),
                createNavController(for: RiderMap(user: user), title: NSLocalizedString("Mapa", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "location")!),
                createNavController(for: InformePeriodos(user: user), title: NSLocalizedString("Ganancias", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "euro")!),
                createNavController(for: CalendarController(user: user), title: NSLocalizedString("Agenda", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "calendar")!),
                createNavController(for: PerfilController(user: user), title: NSLocalizedString("Perfil", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "person")!)
                
            ]
            
        }
        
        override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
            .lightContent
        }
        override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
            return .slide
        }
        
       
        fileprivate func createNavController(for rootViewController: UIViewController,
                                                          title: String,
                                                          image: UIImage) -> UIViewController {
            
           
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
            navController.tabBarItem.title = title
            navController.tabBarItem.image = image
            return navController
            
        }
      

    }
```

And then... the function that send notification to this tabbar from other view controller (without delegates)

```
@objc func updateUser(){
       
       NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateUser"), object: nil)     
           
 }
```